# Por que ocorre este erro de sintaxe?

Tags: python-3.x

Código:

```
print ('oi,tudo bem?')
name = input ()
if name == 'Alice':
    print ('oi, alice.')
    else name != 'Alice'
    print ('Tchau.')
```

Erro:

```
e/emulated/0/qpython/vampi.py" && exit 
File "/storage/emulated/0/qpython/vampi.p 
y", line 5 
else name != 'Alice' 
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax 
1 |u0_a266@jflte:/ $ |
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Está com vários erros:**

- A indentação esta incorreta
- falta `:` depois do `else`
- aliás o `else` deveria ser `elif` e o `:` deveria vir após o `name != 'Alice'`
- falta quebra de linha após o else

o correto seria:

```
print ('oi,tudo bem?')
name = input ()

if name == 'Alice':
    print ('oi, alice.')
elif name != 'Alice':
    print ('Tchau.')
```

Se bem que olhando o script, nem precisa do `!= 'Alice'`, já que pelo primeiro `if` o `elif` seria redundante **neste caso**, então só isso já basta:

```
print ('oi,tudo bem?')
name = input ()

if name == 'Alice':
    print ('oi, alice.')
else:
    print ('Tchau.')
```

Comment: Vlw mano. Estou aprendendo, e agora você me ajudou, na vdd me ensinou. Vlw  